# Tabula only read/convert pages 2- 16

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert an online PDF into pandas so I can work with and manipulate it. I know that Tabula automatically converts into a pandas dataframe but the issue that I am having is that the first page has an extra column in the middle where it contains a column name and then every row below that converts 'NaN'. the other pages don't have that problem.

My thought is that I fix up the first page and then merge it to the rest of them, after adjusting the column headers and such, but the problem I am running into is that I am unable to tell tabula to look at pages 2 - 99 and ignore the page 1.

Any help would be most appreciated:

```
> import tabula
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Documents/HPI/HPI_AT_Tables.pdf'

df = tabula.read_pdf(url, pages = 1)[0]

dfs = df

dfs_cols = ['Metropolitan Statistical Area', 'N/A', 'National Ranking*', '1-Year', 'Quarter', '5-Year']

del dfs['N/A']

url = 'https://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Documents/HPI/HPI_AT_Tables.pdf'


df = tabula.read_pdf(url, pages = '2-99' )[0]
 
dfa = df

dfa
```

When I perform this second command it will return an error and it won't let me past.